# How to change the splash effect size and shape on bottomnavbar?

Tags: flutter

Default Splash Effect:

[image: Default Splash Effect]

How to make our default splash effect on bottom navigation bar not circular shape but rectangle shape and has full width like this?

[image: example]

I have tried to put `inkResponse` but I still don't achieve the same look